# Get told "the TDS protocol stream is not valid" when SET SHOWPLAN_TEXT ON

Tags: sql-server-2008, optimization, sql-execution-plan

I have a slow query that I'm trying to analyze.  MSDN says I can use

```
SET SHOWPLAN_TEXT ON
```

to get SQL Server to return the execution plan information for my query in text.  However, whenever I try to SET SHOWPLAN and then execute my query, I get the message "the TDS protocol stream is not valid".  I do not get this message if I simply select and execute my query.

Any idea why this is happening, and what I can do about it?

Note: I'm running this from SQLExplorer using JDBC, not FROM SQL Studio.  Should that make a difference?
TIA,
Greg

Comment: How are you executing this query? Do you get this error in Management Studio?

Comment: From SQLExplorer.  I'm running on a Mac.

Comment: Yes I would presume it is a JDBC issue. Maybe you could try other methods such as `SET STATISTICS PROFILE ON` or `SET STATISTICS XML ON`

Comment: SET STATISTICS requires the call to complete before you get any information, yes?  My problem is that the call isn't completing (it takes over half an hour, and the connection I was on was dropping before the call completed).

Comment: Same issue was reported in 2012 https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/5c272ad5-45a2-447f-8733-4ffd943f27db/jdbc-driver-throws-exception-with-set-showplanall-on-when-setmaxrows-was-set?forum=sqldataaccess . Now with JDBC 6.0, still the same symptom... : (